# Why does my formula return 0 or 100 when I converted the data types?

Tags: postgresql

I want to count the percentage of people with the name al depending on their id
Here is my script:

```
create table scientist (id integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'al', 'einstein');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (2, 'al', 'newton');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (1, 'al', 'newton');
        insert into scientist (id, firstname, lastname) values (3, 'marie', 'curie');
        select * from scientist;
        
select (sum((case 
when firstname = 'al'then 1
else 0 
end) :: numeric)/(count(id) :: numeric) :: numeric) * 100
from scientist
group by id
```

So the desired table should look like:

```
66 - for id = 1
33 - for id = 2
0 - for id = 3
```

Comment: I don't understand you desired output. For id = 3 the percentage should be 0. Can you please add the ID to each percentage how you expect it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, you are right, for id = 3 it should be 0,  I miswrote. Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `count(id)` as the denominator as that is the number of rows in the group (so 2 for id = 1). You want to divide by the number of rows with firstname = 'al'

```
select id, 
       (count(*) filter (where firstname = 'al')
        / 
       (select count(*)::numeric from scientist where firstname = 'al')) * 100
from scientist
group by id
```

The expression `(count(*) filter (where firstname = 'al')` counts only those rows in the group where the firstname is `al`. And then divides that by the *total* number of rows with al - this is an un-grouped scalar subselect